# Resize Options Menu entries

Tags: java, android, options-menu

How could I resize menu entries to have, for example, only one entry on the bottom row. Here is an example:
[image: entry]
Notice how the "Add" and "Wallpaper" are both on the top and the others are on the bottom. How could I accomplish the same feat, but having just one menu entry on the bottom and two on the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, looking at the documentation there are no methods for `Menu` or `MenuItem` which would allow you to specify this kind of thing. In your supplied image Add and Wallpaper are listed first (you can specify the order of your menu items) and when there are 5 clearly Android automatically puts 2 on the top and 3 on the bottom.